# Loop data a fixed number of times in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to display data via handlebars in a x rows/x columns fashion.

Below is is my sample data and code in handlebars where I want to loop over items depending upon the number of rows and columns in `section1`.

`{{each}}` doesn't not best here as I cannot exit loop. So I want to over loop of columns as soon as columns ends it should start reading rows again.

Below code snippet is of course not working.

```js
var data = {
  "section1" : {
        "columns" : "2",
        "comment" : "This is a comment for the section",
        "items" : {
            "1" : {
                "column" : "1",
                "row" : "1",
                "title" : "API Username",
                "value" : "xyz"
            },
            "2" : {
                "column" : "2",
                "row" : "1",
                "title" : "API Password",
                "value" : "246006"
            } 
        },
        "rows" : "1"
    }
};

var source = document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var target = document.getElementById("target");

try {
  target.innerHTML = template(data.section1);
} catch (ex) {
  console.log(ex.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="section1" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#times rows}}
        <div class="row dialog__right-row-corrector">
        {{#times columns}}
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>API Username</label>
                    <div id="username" class="form-control form-control--transparent"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         {{/times}}
         </div>
    {{/times}}
</script>

<div class="target"></div>
```

source

Comment: Your data layout is silly. Can you change it?

Comment: In other words, your problem is not that `each` does not do what you need. Your problem is that your data layout uses objects like arrays and with a more logical data layout the built-in features of handlebars are more than enough to display the data.

Comment: 1. Yes i can try to change data layout also to fix problem.2. Yes i got your point but can we access "items" directly inside  columns also.  {{#times columns}}
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>API Username</label>
                    <div id="username" class="form-control form-control--transparent"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
         {{/times}}

Comment: See my answer. I think you are trying to solve the wrong end of the problem. Handlebars is fine, your data structure is not. The easiest and most maintainable solution is to change the data structure. This way, standard handlebars would be enough - no external dependencies or strange custom helpers that have no purpose besides dealing with badly structured input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your data is structured is useless. Don't abuse objects for lists. You have a *list of sections*, a *list of rows*, a *list of columns*.

For lists of things, always use arrays, never objects. Create nested arrays of objects if there are lists of things that contain lists of things.

Generally, the data you send to the client via JSON should be a model of what the client is supposed to display, not a model of how the server's database looks like.

Change your server-side code so that it sends data in the following format.

```js
var data = {
    "sections": [
        {
            "id": "section1",
            "comment": "This is a comment for the section",
            "rows": [
                {
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "title": "API Username",
                            "value": "xyz"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "API Password",
                            "value": "246006"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var source = document.getElementById("section").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var target = document.getElementById("target");

target.innerHTML = template(data.sections[0]);
```

```css
#target {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
}
.form-group {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="section" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>{{comment}}</div>
    {{#each rows}}
        <div class="row dialog__right-row-corrector">
        {{#each columns}}
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{title}}</label>
                    <div>{{value}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
         {{/each}}
         </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

If changing the server side is not possible for some reason, instead of trying to bend handlebars against its design, write a small function that changes the incoming data to the layout shown before you pass it to handlebars. A five-line-loop can do that.

Comment: 1. Thanks you so much  @Tomalak  for quick response & expanding my views. I will definitely ask to change server side code if possibly can.  2.  Running this code snippet yields two rows one with API Username & second  "API password". Exception is one row & two columns  (username & password )into that.

Comment: That's because <div> are block elements, by default they do not apper next to each other. Change the template or change the CSS (the code snippet above does not include your grid CSS)

Comment: Although it would be too help from you, but sesiously i don't mind asking. As changing server side code is not my work. Just for my testing Can you please share 5 lines of loops of code for changing layout of incoming data or if you could provide me link in stackoverflow that would be highly appreciated

Comment: No. :) That's your job. You have input and output and the part in between is not difficult. Maybe you need 15 lines of code (it doesn't matter), but I am sure you can do it.